# GLSL Bokeh using Quads and Textures

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to create a depth of field effect with bokeh sprites in GLSL. Specifically, what i would like to do is, for each pixel:

- See if the pixel is out of the focal range
- If it is, draw a quad and apply a texture to provide a bokeh sprite.

This kind of implementation is seen in the [Unreal Engine](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/BokehDepthOfField.html) and by [Matt Pettineo](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/bokeh/), however, both implementations are in DX11 and I'm using OpenGL.

I'm a bit stuck on the drawing a quad and applying a texture bit. Does anyone know how I can do this, or provide any relevant links as to how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You're stuck at "drawing a quad and applying a texture"? And you're trying to implement an advanced depth-of-field technique? Maybe you should slow down a bit, because if you can't draw a textured quad, you're not likely going to be able to draw DOF effects.

Comment: Still, an answer may help future users.